# jQuery UI : draggable behaviour while dropping object using tolerance touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When using jQuery Ui draggable tolerance touch, I am facing problem like when the element touches two droppable elements of same class it is dropped in both the droppables. I have added a image below to describe the problem.

[image: See problem here]

This can be done by using tolerance pointer. But expected behavior is when draggable hovers any point of the droppable it should be activated to drop.
How can I drop only on any one of the element either this or that?

Answer (score 0):

Heres the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tE94H/

To make it short:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
  $(this).droppable('destroy');
}
```

does the trick. Keep in mind, the dropped Elements is the one, where the mousecursor is closer to.